# How to play sound in Reminder class in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm, reminders

I am developing an alarm clock and want to play sound in reminder class.I know that Alarm class works the same way and plays the sound but I want to use reminder as its snooze option is much better than that of alarm class.So is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Sound` property taht is present on [Alarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm%28VS.92%29.aspx) is not present on the `Reminder` class. You are not going to be able to play sounds in a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Alarm class is used for the notification for which a custom sound can be specified.

You have to use the Alarm and Sound property to specify custom sound.

For more information [refer the following link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[For sample refer this link](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-Windows-Phone-Alarms)